# How to run multiple functions as one

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add new roles in bulk and for that i am using the function:

```
add_role(
 'ballroom_dance_instructors_need_western_cape',
 __( 'Ballroom Dance Instructors Need Western Cape' ),
 array(
     'read'         => true,  // true allows this capability
     'edit_posts'   => false ,
 )
);
add_role(
 'ballroom_dance_instructors_need_Abbotsdale',
 __( 'Ballroom Dance Instructors Need Abbotsdale' ),
 array(
     'read'         => true,  // true allows this capability
     'edit_posts'   => false ,
 )
);
add_role(
 'ballroom_dance_instructors_need_fas',
 __( 'Ballroom Dance Instructors Need Fas' ),
 array(
     'read'         => true,  // true allows this capability
     'edit_posts'   => false ,
 )
);
```

How can I still add multiple new roles but with only running the above function once?

Answer (score 0):

You could put it into the `admin_init` hook?

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'your_prefix_add_roles' );
function your_prefix_add_roles() {

    if ( !get_role( 'ballroom_dance_instructors_need_western_cape' ) ) {
        add_role(
            'ballroom_dance_instructors_need_western_cape',
            __( 'Ballroom Dance Instructors Need Western Cape' ),
            array(
                'read'       => true,  // true allows this capability
                'edit_posts' => false ,
            )
        );
    }

    if ( !get_role( 'ballroom_dance_instructors_need_Abbotsdale' ) ) {
        add_role(
            'ballroom_dance_instructors_need_Abbotsdale',
            __( 'Ballroom Dance Instructors Need Abbotsdale' ),
            array(
                'read'       => true,  // true allows this capability
                'edit_posts' => false ,
            )
        );
    }

    if ( !get_role( 'ballroom_dance_instructors_need_fas' ) ) {
        add_role(
            'ballroom_dance_instructors_need_fas',
            __( 'Ballroom Dance Instructors Need Fas' ),
            array(
                'read'       => true,  // true allows this capability
                'edit_posts' => false ,
            )
        );
    }

}
```

This goes into your child-themes ***functions.php*** or within the plugin you are developing.

*N.B. If you attempt to put this in a parent-theme functions.php it may be overridden next time the theme developer releases an update*

**Additional Reading:** [admin_init | Hook | Wordpress Developer Resources](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_init/)

Answer (score 0):

The idea of functions is that it abstracts an single action, so each call to add_role will only add one role at a time. This means that in order to add three roles, you will have to call it three times. If you want to reduce the amount of code, then since you give each one the same permissions you can declare them in a variable and use them by the variable.

```
$premissions = array(
    'read'       => true,  // true allows this capability
    'edit_posts' => false ,
);

add_role(
 'ballroom_dance_instructors_need_western_cape',
 __( 'Ballroom Dance Instructors Need Western Cape' ),
 $permissions
);
add_role(
 'ballroom_dance_instructors_need_Abbotsdale',
 __( 'Ballroom Dance Instructors Need Abbotsdale' ),
 $permissions
);
add_role(
 'ballroom_dance_instructors_need_fas',
 __( 'Ballroom Dance Instructors Need Fas' ),
 $permissions
);
```